# How to decide if a command execution is complete while interacting with a CLI tool through python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, stream, command-line-interface, beeline

I'm running beeline.sh through a python script and reading its output after submitting numerous sequential SQL queries to be executed through it. I can't send all queries in a single run, I have to run each of these queries and inspect their effect individually.

Unfortunately I can't reliably decide if a query was fully processed or not in order to inspect the output and then send another query to proceed with the purpose of my script.

I thought I can wait for the prompt to be printed because that's what I would see after manually running a query through beeline.sh, but the prompt wouldn't be captured while I'm reading the process's stdout line by line!

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['bash', self.beeline_path], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
line = self.process.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8").strip()
while line is not None and len(line) > 0:
    if line.startswith("0: jdbc:hive2://"):
        logging.info("Found prompt: " + line) # Never reached here!
        break
    else:
        line = self.process.stdout.readline().decode("utf-8").strip()
```

So is there a way to make sure the prompt is captured or at least a reliable way to decide when a query was completely processed?

Comment: As an aside, if beeline has a proper shebang and permissions, it's better to use `subprocess.Popen([self.beeline_path], ...)` without the `'bash'` before it; that way the beeline executable can choose its own interpreter, so your code won't suddenly be broken if a future version of beeline is no longer written for bash.

Comment: Use `pexpect` to automate running interactive applications.

Comment: `pexpect` did the trick, thanks a lot. I'm willing to accept this as an answer.